# Git messing head and master

Tags: git

[image]

This point has the correct code with my last and working modifications. It is right or should I do something about it?

I´ve done some conflicts corrections and now this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: You mean that you don't need these 4 commits on your local version of `master` and want to make the local `master` identical to `origin/master`?

Comment: I guess not. I want to make HEAD as my origin/master because HEAD has the right code. I´ve done some conflicts corrections and it is changed to the second picture I´ve uploaded!

Answer (score 2):

- `HEAD` is what you have currently checked out.
- `master` (in green) is your local master branch.
- `origin/master` is where `master` is on the remote `origin` upstream from you.
- `origin/HEAD` indicates what the remote `origin` currently has checked out.

Your `master` branch has diverged from `origin/master`. This is normal as other people push updates, but you probably shouldn't be working on `master` directly. It makes a mess. Instead always work in a feature branch.

There are some things which are concerning.

`origin/HEAD` indicates the remote has your `master` branch checked out. This is weird.

You're currently in a "detached HEAD state" meaning you've checked out a commit that's not on any branch. If you check out another commit, your commits in orange will be unreachable. Git will warn you about this and tell you how to recover them, but it's not a good place to be.

Furthermore, these detached commits are branched off the middle of a branch that's already been merged (red), which is probably not what you wanted.

It's a bit of a mess. How to fix it depends on what you're doing. But at minimum if you want to keep those orange commits, get them into a branch. Then you'll no longer have a detached HEAD and can refer back to those commits.

```
git checkout -b feature/whatever
```

Comment: I´ve uploaded a new picture showing how ti is now after correct some conflicts.

Comment: @MarcelloPatto That looks better. You're still in a detached HEAD state. At this point you can just move `master` to `HEAD` (your current checkout) and you're in good shape. `git branch -f master`.